# What are good tools/techniques for monitoring and debugging IIS performance problems?

Tags: iis, performance, monitoring

I'm looking for the best tools/techniques for monitoring IIS performance problems and then  debugging them. I'm particularly interested in ASP.NET applications.

This may be a combination of tools or there may be something that is good for both?

(I'll add an answer or two based on my experience, for my future reference!, but I hope I'll get some other answers with useful tools to add to my collection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PerfMon is a good basic tool for monitoring.

There are a number of [key performance monitor counters](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Key-Performance-Monitor-Counters.html) that can be used for keeping an eye a server.

A [useful article by Microsoft's Thomas Marquardt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972959.aspx) suggests the following as the minimum counters that should be used for monitoring an ASP.NET application

- Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time
- Process(aspnet_wp)\% Processor Time
- Process(aspnet_wp)\Private Bytes
- Process(aspnet_wp)\Virtual Bytes
- Process(aspnet_wp)\Handle Count
- Microsoft® .NET CLR Exceptions# Exceps thrown / sec
- ASP.NET\Application Restarts
- ASP.NET\Requests Rejected
- ASP.NET\Worker Process Restarts (not applicable to IIS 6.0)
- Memory\Available Mbytes
- Web Service\Current Connections
- Web Service\ISAPI Extension Requests/sec

One counter that I have found useful that isn't mentioned in that article but is 
discussed in a [Thomas Marquardt blog post on ASP.NET Thread Usage](http://blogs.msdn.com/tmarq/archive/2007/07/21/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-0-and-6-0.aspx) is this one:

- ASP.NET Applications\Requests in Application Queue

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of ["Useful tools and add-ons for IIS troubleshooting and IIS7"](http://blogs.msdn.com/dougste/archive/2008/05/16/useful-tools-and-add-ons-for-iis-troubleshooting-and-iis7.aspx)